# How to extract firefoxdriver from selenium server jar?

Tags: ruby, macos, firefox, selenium, watir-webdriver

I tried moving my project over from my OSX 10.8.5 laptop to a mac mini that uses 10.9.1. Both were setup the same way: cucumber/watir-webdriver/ruby 1.9.3. When I tried to run one feature, I got the following error:

```
f.QueryInterface is not a function (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/k2/t6yj80_s3p3byy9fc3jrn9h00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140213-93954-1fpyqq0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8720:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.get'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/k2/t6yj80_s3p3byy9fc3jrn9h00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140213-93954-1fpyqq0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/k2/t6yj80_s3p3byy9fc3jrn9h00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140213-93954-1fpyqq0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/k2/t6yj80_s3p3byy9fc3jrn9h00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140213-93954-1fpyqq0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
```

I downgraded Firefox and watir-webdriver but still was getting the same issue. I read somewhere that running selenium server stand alone installed firefoxdriver xpi. Downloaded/installed java then ran the stand alone selenium server.  I stopped selenium server. Ran my feature test again and it ran without any issues. I assume the firefox driver was not installed. I need to setup a couple other people to be able to run the project so I want to avoid downloading/installing java and selenium server just to get it working if possible.  Is the firefoxdriver xpi named webdriver.xpi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be firefox. Downgraded to an older version and it worked.